# How do I install GeoIP for Django in Heroku?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to install the MaxMind C library API on heroku to support GeoIP for a Django app. I've looked everywhere online, but I could only find methods to install this C library for Ruby on Heroku. How would I be able to install this MaxMind C library API along with the free city and country databases? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a python [Heroku Buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) avaliable on Github that contains geoip.

This ia the ne I found https://github.com/Bouke/heroku-buildpack-python-geoip/tree/master